# how to add an image for scroll in div Tags

Tags: jquery

is there any way we can add image  for  our  scroll bar   for the  div tags. i dnt want to use  the  normal  scroll bar that we  get[i dnt want to use colors for that scroll bar]

once the  the height of the div is set once it  exceeds i need to get my image[ custom image  for the scroll]

is there  any way  we can  get it  done
  any  idea  plz share  with me

Comment: Don't. Please, please, please, please don't. http://web.archive.org/web/20080529040830/http://lists.evolt.org/archive/Week-of-Mon-20030324/138052.html

Comment: @David: I'd agree with that. Google Wave has its own scrollbar that I find hard to use as it behaves differently from the standard one.

Comment: @adrianbanks: I couldn't agree more about your comments about the Google Wave scrollbar. useit.com/alertbox/20050711.html has some good analysis of the pros/cons of rolling your own scrollbars.

Comment: Could you clarify "once the the height of the div is set once it exceeds i need to get my image"?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there isn't a way to set an image as scroller. I think you'll have to create something yourself. Using a mix of [jQuery slider](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider) and `overflow:hidden` on a div, you should be able to customize it pretty well.

But as David links to, it isn't very user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to really uglify your scrollbars (doesn't work in FF try in IE)

```
<style>
body {
scrollbar-base-color: #EFD700;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #219B00;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #00D8B1;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #26005B;
scrollbar-track-color: #03EF00;
}
</style>
```

but I doubt it's a good idea. I think it's difficult to make those things pretty.. unless you use some sort of images for the up and down and events that scroll the div when it's clicked on

Here is a link where you can previous scrollbar styling modifications.

http://www.iconico.com/CSSScrollbar/

Answer (score 0):

Using this javascript class...

```
function Scroller(elemId)
{
    this.intervalId=null;
    this.StartScrollLeft=function() {
        this.intervalId=setInterval("document.getElementById('"+elemId+"').scrollLeft-=5",25);
    }
    this.StartScrollRight=function() {
        this.intervalId=setInterval("document.getElementById('"+elemId+"').scrollLeft+=5",25);
    }
    this.StartScrollUp=function() {
        this.intervalId=setInterval("document.getElementById('"+elemId+"').scrollTop-=5",25);
    }
    this.StartScrollDown=function() {
        this.intervalId=setInterval("document.getElementById('"+elemId+"').scrollTop+=5",25);
    }
    this.StopScroll=function() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
}
```

declare the following for the markup listed below...

```
var oScroller = new Scroller('container');
```

the html markup...

```
<img id="scrollUpControl" src="up.png" onmousedown="oScroller.StartScrollUp()" onmouseup="oScroller.StopScroll()" onmouseleave="oScroller.StopScroll()" />
<img id="scrollDownControl" src="down.png" onmousedown="oScroller.StartScrollDown()" onmouseup="oScroller.StopScroll()" onmouseup="oScroller.StopScroll()" />
<div id="container" style="height:200px; overflow:hidden">...</div>
```